Create python heatmap with two 1D-arrays
I have two very large arrays (80,000+ elements) that i want to create a heatmap for, just like ax.plot draws out the graph but with heatmap values. I don't want to create a 2D-array because of the amount of elements in each array.
Matplotlib's heatmap is an obvious answer but it requires a two-dimensional array that would take hours if not days for me to create because of the amount of elements, so that's out of discussion.
Is there a function that with two 1D-arrays plots a graph but also keeps track of the depth or the heat?
I have tried seaborn.heatmap from seaborn but it requires a DataFrame with a "z" column for value/strength. And that z array is also one-dimensional so it only plots one cell per column and row which is not what we are looking for.
I have also tried matplotlib's pcolormesh which has the same problem, a third two-dimensional array for depth/heat.
Edit
With seaborn heatmap:
import seaborn as sns
data={'x': [1,2,3,4], 'y': [54,5,6,7], 'z': [8,23,9,5]}
heatmap = pd.DataFrame(data=data)
sns.heatmap(heatmap, annot=True, fmt=".1f)

We get:
and with pcolormesh:
ax.pcolormesh([1,2,3],[4,5,6],[[3,4,2],[1,5,6],[4,3,2]]) 
#need a 2d array for depth (third argument) which we want to avoid


Please give a meaningful minimal example of input (let's say max 10 elements) and the exact matching expected output.

Seaborn's sns.kdeplot(x=..., y=...) or sns.histplot(x=..., y=...) could be what you're looking for.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Are you perhaps looking for hist2d?

Yes something like sns.histplot and hist2d like @JohanC and tmdavison pointed out. Is there some way though to create text annotations except looping over the plot?

You can combine numpy's np.histogram2d() with sns.heatmap() to create an annotated 2d histogram. Some things to be careful about, is that sns.heatmap creates categorical axes. And that np.histogram2d has the x and y exchanged from what would be expected for plotting (so, it needs to be transposed).
Here is an example:
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np

iris = sns.load_dataset('iris')
x = iris['sepal_length']
y = iris['petal_length']

heatmap_data, xbins, ybins  = np.histogram2d(x, y, bins=(range(9), range(8)))
ax = sns.heatmap(heatmap_data.T, annot=True, fmt='.0f'  )
ax.set_xticks(range(len(xbins)), xbins, rotation=0 )
ax.set_yticks(range(len(ybins)), ybins, rotation=0 )
ax.set_xlabel('sepal length (cm)')
ax.set_ylabel('petal length (cm)')
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()



Hmm this works in theory but doesn't compile because numpy is unable to allocate that much memory when running with two arrays with 80,000+ element. Or actually, not even with 20,000+ elements

You are changing the requirements. Please edit your post and add more exact requirements.  Preferably with some reproducible test data (e.g. x = np.random.uniform(0, 100, 100000)).  If you're not running on an embedded system, arrays of millions are easily allocated.  However, you need to be careful how many bins you want.   100_000 x 100_0000 might be too many, but you can choose larger bins. Also, a heatmap with that many cells can't show the counts. Please clarify.

I can manipulate the amount of bins but not the size that the bins are counted on. Lets say i want 12 x 12 elements for each and every bin. How would that look like?

You still will have too many bins, impossible to add text to each cell. You also really need to edit your post and add a clear example.

Okay but if one bin was way more, like 10,000 x 10,000. How would the code look like, because i don't really know how to change or use the params? I also edited the question :)

JohanC did you see my last comment?

Your post is still lacking a clear example. How does your input data look like? What is the range (min/max),  the type (floats?) of the values? How many data is there? How many cells do you want to show horizontally and vertically? You need to adapt the bins in np.histogram2d), for example np.histogram2d(x, y, bins=(30,20)) to get 30 bins in the x-direction and 20 for y. Did you look into the documentation?
